# Why would an AsyncTask not start if started/stopped repeatedly?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

So, I've been debugging an issue in my game, where if I start then stop it repeatedly, I have noticed that sometimes an Asynctask doesn't seem to get started, even though I appear to do the right thing to get it started. I've removed a lot of unnecessary code to show what happens, but basically I'm seeing that I'm about to start an Asynctask, but the task never gets started.

```
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG,"About to execute");
    Play_level.execute();
}

AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Integer> Play_level=new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer>(){
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer ...time) {
            //Stuff goes in here.
     }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d(TAG,"In Task");
    }

};
```

And the logcat shows:

```
03-10 19:28:16.983: D/Level(1535): About to execute
03-10 19:28:17.503: D/Level(1535): onStop()
03-10 19:28:17.993: D/Level(1535): onPause()
03-10 19:28:19.174: D/AJEG(1535): Starting Tongue
03-10 19:28:19.313: D/Level(1535): ImageList Previously Loaded
03-10 19:28:19.313: D/Level(1535): About to execute
03-10 19:28:19.853: D/Level(1535): onStop()
03-10 19:28:20.283: D/Level(1535): onPause()
03-10 19:28:21.464: D/AJEG(1535): Starting Tongue
03-10 19:28:21.604: D/Level(1535): ImageList Previously Loaded
03-10 19:28:21.604: D/Level(1535): About to execute
03-10 19:28:22.134: D/Level(1535): onStop()
03-10 19:28:22.404: D/Level(1535): onPause()
03-10 19:28:23.504: D/AJEG(1535): Starting Tongue
03-10 19:28:23.644: D/Level(1535): ImageList Previously Loaded
03-10 19:28:23.644: D/Level(1535): About to execute
03-10 19:28:24.184: D/Level(1535): onStop()
```

Furthermore, no amount of re-entering the task seems to be able to re-start the code, as is shown by the last bit of text.

Just to give a bit more context, Starting Tongue is played in the onStart() of the parent activity (AJEG), Level is the name of the activity I'm starting. The ImageList command can be safely ignored, but I've included it for completeness. Part of the `doInBackground` includes the text "Starting Level _*", where _* is the level that is about to be started. onStop() and onPause() are in the method to show when `onStop()` and `onPause()` occur in the Level task.

Comment: "onStop() and onPause() are in the method to show when onStop() and onPause() occur in the Level task." - Perhaps I misunderstand you but that makes no sense. `onStop()` is never called before `onPause()`. Looking at your logcat that seems to be what is being reported however.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: You are right, but I did do what I said I was doing... It seems to me that onStop() is called right after "About to Execute" is posted... Furthermore, the onStop() isn't called on the times when AsyncTask was executed correctly. Hmmm...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the solution to the problem is as stated in [this blog article](http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2010/05/limitations-of-asynctask.html):

> AsyncTask uses a static internal work queue with a hard-coded limit of
>   10 elements

So, essentially I had an AsyncTask that never finished, to the amount of 10, by re-starting my thread so much. To get around this, I did the following:

1. I converted the AsyncTask to a class, and ensured that only one instance was running, as mah suggested.
2. I canceled the task in the onStop() command, as Mike D suggested in his comment.
3. I made sure that I check to see if the ASyncTask is canceled in the `doInBackground`.

The result is something like this:

```
private LevelPlay Play_level;

public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    Play_level.cancel(true);
}

public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Play_level=new LevelPlay();
    Play_level.execute();
}


class LevelPlay extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer>
{
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer ...time) {
     }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d(TAG,"In Task");
            Boolean keepRunning=true;
        while(keepRunning && !isCancelled ())
        {
                 //DoStuffHere
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html you'll notice: `The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)`.

In your application you create a single AsyncTask and are trying to re-use it. Instead, create a new instance of it for each execution.

Comment: No exception was thrown. However, I still changed things around such that the AsyncTask was a class within a class, a new instance was created in each OnStart(), and the same problem resulted.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code that works for me:

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {

    private Thread worker;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        worker = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            private void updateUI(final List<Object> list)
            {
                if(worker.isInterrupted()){
                    return;
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        // Update view and remove loading spinner etc...
                    }
                });
            }

            private List<Object> download()
            {
                // Simulate download
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                return new ArrayList<Object>();
            }

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Thread run()");
                updateUI(download());
            }

        });
        worker.start(); }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        worker.interrupt();
    }
}
```

And the [**Limitation on AsyncTask**](http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2010/05/limitations-of-asynctask.html)

Hope it Helps.

Comment: +1 for the blog article, which contained the key I was missing (10 maximum AsyncTasks can be opened, and I wasn't closing them...)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your talkning about the `onStart()` method of an `Activity`,  it may be because your application was not removed from memory when you returned to it, meaning your `onStart()` method is probably not being called.  You might want to consider using `onResume()` or `onRestart()` (or maybe both), and possibly cancel the `AsyncTask` in `onPause()`.  This would also mean, in your background task, you should check if has been cancelled.

As to why its happening, see mah's answer.

[Activty lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: OnStart() was called, as is evidence from the LogCat "About to execute"

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto  Then mah has is right in why its happening.  You might want to look into killing the task when the activity enters the background and recreating a new on each time the activity comes to the foreground, or checking if its null before you create it.